# 300 million items in a Map

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, hashmap

1. If each of them is guaranteed to have a unique key (generated and
   enforced by an external keying system) which Map implementation is
   the correct fit for me? Assume this has to be optimized for
   concurrent lookup only (The data is initialized once during the
   application startup).
2. Does this 300 million unique keys have any positive or negative
   implications on bucketing/collisions?
3. Any other suggestions?

My map would look something like this

```
Map<String, <boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean>>
```

Comment: Just a question: are you sure you want to store 300M such items in a Map in memory? If it is a simple Map<Integer, Integer>, you already need 2.4G of memory to keep 300M such items.

Comment: If it is not tooo many lookups per second and you do NOT want very high throughput; I will recommend you to try out NoSQL which will solve memory problems; and will give reasonable performance.

Comment: @Dan I am not sure how 300M equate to 2.5 GB of memory. I measured the map size for 10 million data points (integer key and an object that holds four booleans as the value) using SizeOf utility and it came to around 1 GB.

Comment: How much RAM have you got, and roughly how large a heap are you planning to have?

Comment: @Pangea: If 10M entries take a gig, you're looking at 30GB for the 300M entries, right?

Comment: @NPE right and I am aware of this fact. I am just trying to understand how Dan came to 2.4 GB conclusion.

Comment: Map<Integer, Integer> requires less than your Map<Integer, Object>. However, if 10M of your records need 1G then 300M will need 30G of memory. Will you have that much?

Comment: One of my records will need 8 bytes. 8 * 300M = 2.4G

Comment: @Dan I want to avoid 30G if I can. My keys are strings by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use a map, this needs to much memory. Especially in your case.
Store the values in one data array, and store the keys in a sorted index array.
In the sorted array you use binSearch to find the position of a key in data[].

The tricky part will be building up the array, without running out of memory.

you dont need to consider concurreny because you only read from the data

Further try to avoid to use a String as key. try to convert them to long.
the advantage of this solution: search time garuanteed to not exceed log n. even in worst cases when keys make problems with hashcode

Comment: How does storing the values in an array take up significantly less memory?

Comment: An array of ints is much more efficient than say an array of Objects.

Comment: because objects in java needs 12 bytes at least.

Comment: @AlexWien How could an array of ints *not* be more efficient? If the data is just four booleans it could even be an array of bytes and a bitmask would be sufficient.

Comment: @AlexWien my keys are in the String form. I can't change that as I have the keys assigned by an external system. Is there a way to convert the String keys to int? May be using the hashCode() but i might get collisions.

Comment: @AlexWien how is a long key efficient that a string key?could you please explain in detail?

Comment: a long key is a primtive , a compare runs at cpu speed in one or more cpu cycles. a string compare is 100 times more costly, look at algorithms how to comoare strings,myou have to look atbeach char, till the result is clear.

Comment: you could ask how the strings keys are created, maybe its a formula, which then you can use to write an optimized hashcode function. further it depneds on your app, do you need frequent lookups for one string key, or do you need that only once.

Answer (score 3):

Other suggestion? You bet.

Use a proper key-value store, [**Redis**](http://redis.io/) is the first option that comes to mind. Sure it's a separate process and dependency, but you'll win big time when it comes to proper system design.

There should be a *very* good reason why you would want to couple your business logic with several gigs of data in same process memory, even if it's ephemeral. I've tried this several times, and was always proved wrong.

Comment: @Already considered this but network latency + un-marshalling time might be the problem. Otherwise I would have stored all this in DB itself using in-memory tables.

Comment: Deploy the process on the same machine, you won't even be doing tcp sockets, rather unix sockets, overhead is minimal to non-existent. And again, a big win on maintainability and scalability. If I were your system architect you'd have to work very hard to convince me the performance improvement is worth it.

Comment: But I have this application running in a cluster and hence I would require running the redis on each of the machines.

Comment: Yet another very good reason why you'd want a proper data store. Like I've said, I have direct experience with such a case, tried to implement in-memory, and failed miserably. Sure, performance was good initially, but scale issues quickly made us backtrack.

Comment: But why Redis over in-memory table of RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you can simply use `TreeMap`, because it will give you `O(log(n))` for data search due to its sorted structure. Furthermore, it is eligible method, because, as you said, all data will be loaded at startup.

Comment: needs to mmuch memory, a left, right and balance info is need for evry node

Comment: @AlexWien I don't think, that 300_000_000 strings + boolean[4] is too much. Modern servers have 64..256 GB of RAM. No problem for Java x64.

Comment: @AlexWien BTW, your method with `data[]` is quite good. I also would use such approach in common case. But in some cases you strongly need `Map` structures.

Comment: i work in an IT company, but 64GB has only one server (which i know) and on this one a huge number of virtualized servers are running. so you rarley will have huge memory for one app. look if you know somebody which has 64 GB available for one application.

Comment: @AlexWien Yes, I know somebody with 96 GB RAM server just for developing purposes for single Java application. Furthermore, it is not a problem to but a server with cost ~$10k for serious IT company.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep everything in memory, then you will need to use some library meant to be used with these amount of elements like [Huge collections](http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections). On top of that, if the number of writes will be big, then you have to also think about some more sophisticated solutions like [Non-blocking hash map](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/)